# SNPs Linkage disequilibrium in R

Tags: r

I have to perform a linkage disequilibrium test between pairwise of SNPs. I have 3745 SNPs in 170 genotypes.

- Which one of the packages would you recommend or have experience with and,
- Most importantly; how do I have to set my data matrix to use well the package and functions (rows&columns).

Comment: Questions that are only about how to use R are off topic here (as are requests for packages / code, etc.).

Comment: Try the Bioconductor list

Answer (score 1):

Indeed there are multiple packages to compute LD. However, you actually don't need any package since the core R functions are sufficient.

So given a $n\times p$ genotype matrix $m$ with $n$ subjects and $p$ SNPs (genotypes are usually called the alleles, or the value in the cells, while SNPs are the columns) you can use `cor(m)` of the genotype matrix to obtain the pairwise correlations.

The coding of the alleles (or the cells) is usually done the following:

- 2    Homozygous for first allele
- NA   Missing genotype
- 1    Heterozygous
- 0    Homozygous for second allele

The first allele is usually the minor allele.

If you really want the significance levels of the pairwise correlations as well you can use the `rcor()` function from the package `Hmisc`. If you want some nice heatmaps, look also at `LDheatmap`.

However, please take a look at [plink](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/). Plink is the most commonly used software to analyse these kind of data and basically standard for association studies.